# Burger and chips calculation puzzle 2

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

[image]

This is easy though I think it is very fun to think about!

```
S+S+S=30
S+H+H=20
H+F+F=9
H+F*S=?
```

Comment: The word format is misleading because the fries are not the same.

Comment: Even if there wasn't the misleading change in the number of fries, there is still an infinite number of solutions to this puzzle.

Comment: All of your questions so far have been labelled as "easy", or "for beginners", and all of them have been heavily downvoted. You may want to consider trying to come up with more challenging puzzles in future. Very few people here are beginners.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is

> 15, not 25

since

> there's only one bag of fries in the last line, not two.

About half of the puzzles of this type seem to have this trap.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

> 15

Equation:

> $5 + 1 \times 10 = 15$