# Burger and chips calculation puzzle

Tags: calculation-puzzle

++= 30

++=20

++=25

+++++=?

This is easy but fun! 
Try to find out the last question!

Comment: This is the same as [Easy riddle!!! Not that hard very easy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97554/easy-riddle-not-that-hard-very-easy)

Comment: Oh that’s the same person cause I made a new account sorry!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 40.

Here's my work:

f=box of fries; b=burger; d=drink

3d = 30 --> d = 10;

2f + d = 20 --> 2f + 10 = 20 --> f = 5;

b + 2d = 25 --> b + 20 = 25 --> b = 5;

2f + 2d+ 2b = 10 + 20 + 10 = 40

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! A couple notes: First, this question will likely be closed as a duplicate soon; I would recommend avoiding posting answers to duplicate questions. Second, it is customary to hide key information about the solution to a puzzle with the ">!" format. Thanks for contributing to the site, and I hope to see you around. Happy Puzzling!